# C# AppDomain load(byte[]) throws FileLoadException (HResult 0x80131040 aka manifest error)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-4.0, updates

I have a separate .Net 4 application to upgrade main application remotely (functions). Due to recent changes, it now shares reference to the same file as the main application. This of course prevents it from copying over new dll that would overwrite that file (basically dll that, among other things, handles settings - from where I will need to retrieve some data which prevents just not loading it). Browsing thru SO I think I have managed to get further, but have now hit a road block.

I tried to load the dll from resources (does not work due to the application finding older common.dll from the application directory, and if I load from resources then there is type conflict between the two different versions of same dll). Because there does not seem to be any way to change DisallowApplicationBaseProbing setting for default application domain (to prevent loading older common.dll from the directory), I have created launcher application that will launch the upgrader to newly created application domain with that option set. In order to prevent the launcher getting references to the settings file via reference to the upgrader program, I have included both as resources (if referenced directly, it's subreferences cause the file to be loaded from application directory and to block the copying of files), which you can see below - I have similar blocks for other configurations.

```
<When Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\Libraries\Common\bin\Debug\Common.dll">
      <Link>Common.dll</Link>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\Deployment\Upgrader\bin\Debug\Upgrader.dll">
      <Link>Upgrader.dll</Link>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
</When>
```

As far as I can see, correct dll's will be picked to the resources. In the launcher I have the following code (it does find the data, and earlier has loaded the file correctly - but has now broken down).

```
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up AppDomain..");
        var setup = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation;
        setup.DisallowApplicationBaseProbing = true;

        createdDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("CorrectedCommonDomain", null, setup);
        using (Stream s = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("UpgraderLauncher.Common.dll"))
        {
            if (s == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not load common.dll correctly!");
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Could not load internal common.dll resource.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Loading common.dll..");
            byte[] data = new byte[s.Length];
            s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            commonDllAssembly = createdDomain.Load(data);
            Console.WriteLine("Loading common.dll is done.");
        }
```

The problem arises on "createdDomain.Load(data);" part, which throw FileLoadException (HResult 0x80131040 aka manifest error). Full exception details below.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in UpgraderLauncher.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Common, Version=1.0.5256.21424, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=86e85f643d1e5711' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Upon rebuilding the common.dll (and subsequently the launcher), the version of dll in exception message is updated. How should I proceed, and how can the manifest of byte loaded dll be different from itself? (all of the files are strongly signed.)

Comment: You just have an old version of the DLL embedded.  It isn't very clear how that happened, probably a build order problem.  Or you just plain using a stale build of the DLL.  Letting the [AssemblyVersion] auto-increment sure rubs your nose into it.

Comment: Could be there is some build order problem since the launcher is not referencing anything - but it doesn't depend on anything either. The problem happens when trying to load the dll to the custom appdomain, before I try loading anything that needs it. And I am loading the assembly that I have included, and as it is not referenced in the project.. how can it be old ? (even stale dll's should load fine at that point as they are not used)

Comment: I have checked the build order - launcher is built last so it should not provide problems when whole solution is built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this one solved. The problem was that the assembly was loaded into both domains (since there is a reference to the assembly in the launcher, it is also loaded to the default AppDomain, which instead of loading the dll it was asked instead proceeds to load the manifest from the old file from within the directory where the launcher is, thus ending in manifest conflict between the old file and bytes contained within the launcher).
To solve error in similar situations, instead of having any code loading the files within the default AppDomain, move the loading to happen inside the created AppDomain. To do this, save the byte[] to the appdomain data:

```
createdDomain.SetData("CommonDllAssembly", data);
```

And then within the code that runs on the created domain:

```
byte[] bytes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("CommonDllAssembly") as byte[];
commonDllAssembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
```

This prevents the mentioned error from popping up.